# How do I stop MySQL errors output to the browser from containing the DB password?

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, pdo, zend-db

When the server has a MySQL config or other error it prints the MySQL user name and password to the browser. This is a security risk in that if the SQL db is unavailable it will also print the password to the browser.

In this example I intentionally set the password incorrectly, here is the output:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception
>   'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied
>   for user 'username'@'localhost' (using
>   password: YES)' in
>   /usr/local/zend/share/ZendFramework/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php:129
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /usr/local/zend/share/ZendFramework/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(129):
>   PDO->__construct('mysql:host=loca...',
>   'drupal', 'password', Array) #1
>   /usr/local/zend/share/ZendFramework/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(96):
>   Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->_connect() #2 
>   /usr/local/zend/share/ZendFramework/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(459):
>   Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect() #3
>   /usr/local/zend/share/ZendFramework/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238):
>   Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('DESCRIBE
>   `site_...', Array) #4
>   /usr/local/zend/share/ZendFramework/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(156):
>   Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('DESCRIBE`site_...') #5
>   /usr/local/zend/share/ZendFramework/library/Zend/Db/Table/Abstract.php(823):
>   Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysq in
>   /usr/local/zend/share/ZendFramework/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php
>   on line 144

Here is the current config code in the index.php file

```
global $db;
if ($CFG->flagDBAdapters) {
    foreach ($config->db as $config_name => $database) {
        $dbAdapters[$config_name] = Zend_Db::factory($database->adapter,
        $database->config->toArray());
        if ((boolean) $database->default) {
            Zend_Db_Table::setDefaultAdapter($dbAdapters[$config_name]);
            $db = $dbAdapters[$config_name];
        }
    }
    Zend_Registry::set('dbAdapters', $dbAdapters);
```

I tried reading more about PDO and inserting

```
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT);
```

That just resulted in a different error

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method
>   Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql::setAttribute()
>   in
>   /usr/local/zend/apache2/htdocs/source/index.php
>   on line 301

Can anyone help point me in the right direction as to what I should be looking for?

Comment: did you Try  to surround the bloc that cause the error by a Try Catch statement.?

Answer (score 2):

Well it's more like Zend Framework related question rather than general PHP issue.
So, ZF should have it's own ways to disable such behavior.

As of PHP, the `display_errors` setting sould be always turned off on the production server

Comment: I believe that's the default output of an unhandled PDO exception. It's not caused specifically by the Zend Framework...

Comment: @meagar I used to use PDO and it had no Stack trace

Comment: I looked into Zend and found that inserting $message = ''; into the zend library Exception.php stops the issue, however its bad practice to modify the framework. `class Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception extends Zend_Db_Exception
{
    protected $_chainedException = null;

    public function __construct($message = '', $code = 0, Exception $e = null)
    {
        if ($e && (0 === $code)) {
            $code = $e->getCode();
        }
        //adding $message = ''; below stops the error output
 $message = '';
        parent::__construct($message, $code, $e);
    }`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`set_error_handler`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) to specify your own error handler, which should display something much more user-friendly in production while displaying more detailed debugging data during development/testing.

Comment: as a matter of fact, such an output IS already a result of using custom error handler.

Comment: No, its regular PHP error before `Stack trace: ` and the rest is custom error handler. built-in error handler would never print db password

Answer (score 0):

putting the @ symbol in front of a statement suppresses errors from being outputed.

Comment: Please, improve your knowledge before trying to answer. putting the @ symbol in front of a statement suppresses errors from being **raised** at all. It has nothing to do with outputting actually. While output should be controlled using other ways.

Comment: @Col Shrapnel: that's rather misleading. @ sets the error reporting level to 0 during the statement execution. While it certainly possible to write code that doesn't raise errors if the reporting level is zero, PHP itself will happily continue to raise errors, and you can still use trigger_error(). Any custom error handler is still called regardless.

Comment: @Paul I can't believe that such experienced programmer can say such a nonsense like "it certainly possible to write code that doesn't raise errors". There is no point in using @ at all, and I can't believe you advocate it's usage. Something got rotten in this realm...

Comment: I'm not advocating its usage, I just thought it worth pointing out that your wording was misleading, and it suggests that internally, PHP checks the reporting level is non-zero *before* deciding to raise an error. It is the reporting function itself which generally performs this check.